# Docker wordpress installation on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: wordpress, docker, docker-compose, phpmyadmin

Hi there what should be a straight forward installation of Wordpress and PHPMyadmin on Docker on Ubuntu 20.04 is throwing errors in the STDOUT and subsequently when attempting to view WordPress in the browser I am getting a non-specific database error.

Firstly my yaml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'   
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wpdb
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:5.4.1
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_NAME: wpdb
      WORDPRESS_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 443:443
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3333:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password

And Now the output from **docker-compose up**

Starting mysql              ... done
Starting test2_phpmyadmin_1 ... done
Starting wordpress          ... done
Attaching to mysql, test2_phpmyadmin_1, wordpress
mysql         | 2020-05-13 08:25:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
mysql         | 2020-05-13 08:25:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
phpmyadmin_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.26.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
mysql         | 2020-05-13 08:25:52+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.20-1debian10 started.
mysql         | 2020-05-13T08:25:52.527362Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
mysql         | 2020-05-13T08:25:52.527443Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.20) starting as process 1
phpmyadmin_1  | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.26.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
mysql         | 2020-05-13T08:25:52.534595Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
phpmyadmin_1  | [Wed May 13 08:25:52.250991 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.4.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
phpmyadmin_1  | [Wed May 13 08:25:52.251029 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
mysql         | 2020-05-13T08:25:52.671334Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
mysql         | 2020-05-13T08:25:52.773825Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
wordpress     | [13-May-2020 08:25:52 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
mysql         | 2020-05-13T08:25:52.864314Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
mysql         | 2020-05-13T08:25:52.871773Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
mysql         | 2020-05-13T08:25:52.908753Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.20'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
wordpress     | [13-May-2020 08:25:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  mysqli::__construct(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.4' (using password: NO) in Standard input code on line 22
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.4' (using password: NO)
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.4' (using password: NO)
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.4' (using password: NO)
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.4' (using password: NO)
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.4' (using password: NO)
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.4' (using password: NO)
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.4' (using password: NO)
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.4' (using password: NO)
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | MySQL Connection Error: (1045) Access denied for user 'root'@'172.26.0.4' (using password: NO)
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | WARNING: unable to establish a database connection to 'db'
wordpress     |   continuing anyways (which might have unexpected results)
wordpress     | 
wordpress     | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.26.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress     | AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.26.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
wordpress     | [Wed May 13 08:26:19.911848 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1] AH00163: Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) PHP/7.3.17 configured -- resuming normal operations
wordpress     | [Wed May 13 08:26:19.911906 2020] [core:notice] [pid 1] AH00094: Command line: 'apache2 -D FOREGROUND'
```

And as I said when I attempt to access WordPress on **localhost:8080** I get

**Error establishing a database connection**

PhpMyadmin works fine on **localhost:3333**

Any ideas???????

Oh yes I have been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BfrVWwJv8ls

Thanks : )

Comment: It's not related to your problem, but the `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` variable passed in to the phpMyAdmin container doesn't do anything; that directive is for the MySQL one only and has no effect on phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 2):

The error indicates that WordPress is unable to connect to your database container. The reason is likely due to WordPress not knowing the credentials because the ENV vars passed to the WP container is not using the keys that it expects.

If you adjust the keys used for the WP container to match the ones you see here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/ it should run. Try it like this:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'   
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wpdb
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:5.4.1
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wpdb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 443:443
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3333:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
```

Comment: Thanks I have used the linked code to make changes to mine and now all is good. : )

Comment: Glad that the docs were able to help. Sometimes videos skip over things that are important so having some documentation to copy/paste/edit helps a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is my updated code:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    volumes:
       - ./db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'   
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wpdb
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password

  wordpress:
    image: wordpress:5.4.1
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./html:/var/www/html
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wpdb
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: user
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - 8080:80
      - 443:443
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3333:80
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: db
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```